# Intersection of the values of classes with the data area in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the same classes with different values (0, 1, ..., 11)

```
  <input class="cl" value="0">
  <input class="cl" value="1">
  ...
```

And Array:

```
   var data = [3,5,8];
```

How can I `$(".cl").addClass('js-add')` only for inputs which crossing with array data?

Comment: There is no `</input>`. Inputs self close.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.filter()` with `$.inArray()`:

```
$('.cl').filter(function(){
  return  $.inArray( parseInt(this.value), data)>-1;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e0ow1206/)**

Comment: @stress_tn: glad it helps. look at the comment from  j08691. and modify the dom accordingly. :)

Comment: It was speed example here, code is correct! Many thanks guys!